# How to use svg icons just like "font awesome" icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, font-awesome

I am new to front-end development. And one of the sample project that I am going through uses "font awesome" icons instead of images. [Font-Awesome Link](http://fontawesome.io/) And every where instead of `<img src>` all I find is `<i class= "">`. I researched a little and found out these icons are basically svg files. So, I created couple of svg files for learning purpose. But I don't know how to correctly include svg files.

**Question 1:** So I am putting svg files in my own project and calling them like  `<img src = "images/sms_connect_logo.svg"/>`. I am able to see the icon but is it the right way to add icons. I wanted to use something like `<i class = "blabla">` to get the desired result as its done in sample project.

**Question 2:** Currently, the icon I have created is of black colour. I want it to be light gray in colour. So do I need to create another SVG file of same icon with light gray colour so the same black icon can be changed to gray by some css tweaking. (Using the Power of SVG files).

I am totally new so I might not have asked question the right way. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: You a looking for [`Sprites`](https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: http://fontawesome.io/

Answer (score 5):

I use [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) to build a custom icon font. You can import icons from fontawesome and other icon libraries, plus add your own very easily.

It is also nice because you are able to select only the icons you need for your app, which can greatly reduce the size of the css and font files

Comment: But then, once I have the icon, how do I create the sprite and how do I create the "include file" that will take the name and put the correct icon from the sprite.  In other words, is there a utility that helps me create my own custom "font-awesome-replacement" fonts?

Comment: @pashute What you have described is exactly what the icomoon app does - select icons from different icon sets (ex. font awesome) and even import your own sprites (ex. svg images).  After selecting the icons you want, click the "Generate Font" button and it gives you a zip file containing the font and CSS files.

Comment: This is *great!  I.e. icomoon comes with one important caveat: SVG strokes are not exported!  (Only fills are.)  So most icons will work, but some (that may have a little more detail) will not survive the export!!